# Creating a character, is Noble a class or a background?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, class, background

I am getting back into D&D after about 15 years. Reading through the Players Handbook it refers to Noble as a class but it is found in the Background section.

Super novice question and I apologize, but I am trying to clear up my misunderstanding.

Is Noble a class, or a background? Of both? Meaning could I have (dumb example) Tiefling Druid with Noble background? Or would it just be a Tiefling Noble?

Comment: Out of curiosity, where do you see it referred to as a class?

Comment: Welcome to the site! I see you already took the tour so you can check the [help] if you need further guidance. Good luck and happy gaming!

Answer (score 50, accepted):

### The word "class" is being used in two different senses here.

Noble, *as a social class stratum in a Feudal/Medieval* setting, is a different use of the term than "Class" for a PC such as Druid, Fighter, Ranger, Wizard, etc, that has a progression from level 1 - 20 with game mechanical benefits.

### Answer: Noble is a background for D&D 5e, not a PC class.

Any PC can come from a Noble social class if the Noble Background (Chapter 4) is chosen.

#### Genre Conventions

When you are dealing with a fantastical setting that has kings, queens, princes, lords, and such broadly rooted in the typical feudal / medieval / Renaissance cultural setting from Western Civ, class differences are embedded in the default setting.  As you can see in the text for the Noble background:

> You might be a pampered aristocrat unfamiliar with work or discomfort, a former merchant just elevated to the nobility, or a disinherited scoundrel with a disproportionate sense of entitlement. (Basic Rules, p. 42)

*Aristocrats* and nobles come from a particular social class in the default setting.   Commoners come from a different layer of the societal strata.  See also this feature:

**Feature: Position of Privilege**

> Thanks to your noble birth, people are inclined to think the best of
>   you. You are welcome in high society, and people assume you have the
>   right to be wherever you are. The common folk make every effort to
>   accommodate you and avoid your displeasure, *and other people of high
>   birth treat you as a member of the same social sphere. You can secure
>   an audience with a local noble if you need to*.

Aside: *Commoners* have an NPC default description, as do *Nobles*.  That is in the Monster Manual (or the Monster / NPC appendix, Basic Rules) and is separate from the character creation of a PC.

Answer (score 12):

## Noble is a background, not a class

It is a background and you can find  the mechanics of choosing to be a [Noble](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/personality-and-background#Noble) under Backgrounds in Chapter 4 of the PHB (Personality and Background.)

It is also **not** listed as option in Chapter 3: Classes.

### Your example

In your example, you would be a Tiefling Druid with the Noble background. You pick your race, your class, and your background.